# Class D amplifier with +-70V rails

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, class-d

I'm trying to design a class D amplifier with rails that have +70V and -70V. Most designs I find online switch at the mosfets between the +rails and ground. Is it possible to get the mosfets to switch between the +70V and -70V?
This is the circuit I designed in LTspice for now. I know that the output of the mosfets should be conected to TS but I have it to ground for now. The opamps I use are also something I tried so my mosfets would work but I can delete them if needed. I'm using this driver because it's the only one I could find for now in LTspice. If someone has a circuit that uses a different driver or I HAVE to use a different driver please send me something so I can implement it in LTspice. (I know the mosfets will get a lot of current to handle in this scheme but I just need the output of the mosfets to be between +70 and -70V for now. The filter and load will be added later.)
[image: Circuit for now]

I hope someone can help me.

EDIT:
[image]

This is the ouput for this scheme.

[image]

This is the output with ground.

Comment: Ahem, the op-amp's absolute maximum supply voltage is +/- 20 volts and, what are you doing with the bootstrap circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka the op-amp's can be deleted out of the circuit if nessecary. I just added them to level up the inuput of the mosfets. The bootstrap should be from the output of the mosfets to the input TS in the IC. But with doing that I can't get the ouput of the mosfets to switch between +/- 70 volts.

Comment: I suggest that you look at "Half Bridge" circuits which are mostly used to drive motors  but are similar to class-D output stages. Why are you using the MOSFETs at the output as source followers? That makes no sense as that means they drop more voltage than needed, harming efficiency. Why would you need a symmetric supply? Class D amplifiers are usually in a bridge configuration so that the negative supply isn't needed. Switching the MOSFETs on/off fast enough will be a challenge, opamps are not gonna cut it. I suggest you study existing designs to learn why things are done as they are.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with a dozen parts? https://hifiakademie.de/pics/features/powerdac_533x400_06.jpg?si=MTU4MzQwNzE1Ny4zNTU2fDE3My4zMi41MS45N3wg

Comment: @jan then what is the point of the circuit if you are fudging over what I told you?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the way I put the mosfets like that was just trail and error. This way it seemed to work somethimes and I tried to get the logic behind it after it worked. I'll try to look at Half bridge circuits, thanks.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I just need to design one

Comment: @Andyaka Where the mosfets come together I need it to be a PWM between +70 and -70 and not between +70 and ground. (if that awnsers your question, my english isn't that great)

Comment: Why can't you have your PWM controller bolted to -70 volts instead of ground. If it's a problem feeding control signals to the driver, that is solved in many ways.

Comment: @Andyaka if that fixes it for a different driver that would be fine. I'll look into that because it seems like the one that LTspice has doesn't react well to that high of PWM

Comment: Jan you have no hope of designing one until you master how hey work so start educating yourself https://www.hypex.nl/p/application-notes-white-papers/  << and this is just a start. A simple logic diagram  cannot possibly define all the aspects of any power amplifier especially MOSFET's  Definition“Digital amplifier” is an oxymoron. Read ever paper and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just move your driver to be at the negative rail: -

[image]

Then opto or magnetically isolate the two input signals to where they are sourced.

I don't think you need U1 or U2 either but I have suggested how you would power them just in case.

Comment: Aren't the power pins of U1 and U2 reversed?

Comment: Oops I meant to say -70 volts.....

Comment: If he doesn't understand this https://www.hypex.nl/img/upload/doc/an_wp/WP_AES124BP_A_universal_grammar%20of%20class_D.pdf why are you recommending this low fidelity solution?

Comment: I guess he has to begin somewhere.

Comment: I guess cheap and dirty with layout resonances like crazy, he will learn to be humble with failures or worse.